# New WP installation on Hostgator domain but not working

Tags: installation

I have installed the Wordpress on a domain from Hostgator and I reached the following:

Congratulations, the software was installed successfully
WordPress has been successfully installed at :
http://www.alijoohy.org
Administrative URL : http://www.alijoohy.org/wp-admin/

We hope the installation process was easy.

NOTE: Softaculous is just an automatic software installer and does not provide any support for the individual software packages. Please visit the software vendor's web site for support!

Regards,
Softaculous Auto Installer

But when I enter the urls above I get nothing!

Entering the first url:

If you feel you have reached this page in error, please contact the web site owner:

webmaster@alijoohy.org
It may be possible to restore access to this site by following these instructions for clearing your dns cache.
If you are the web site owner, it is possible you have reached this page because:

The IP address has changed.
There has been a server misconfiguration.
The site may have been moved to a different server.
If you are the owner of this website and were not expecting to see this page, please contact your hosting provider.

Entering the second url:

The server can not find the requested page:

[www.alijoohy.org/sapp-wp-signon.php?pass=g08sjjh5zgvoxmbkxz9piszjlfmg3alo](http://www.alijoohy.org/sapp-wp-signon.php?pass=g08sjjh5zgvoxmbkxz9piszjlfmg3alo) (port 80)
Please forward this error screen to www.alijoohy.org's WebMaster.

Apache/2.2.25 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.25 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 Server at [www.alijoohy.org](http://www.alijoohy.org) Port 80.

What should I do now?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you followed the [process here](https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/how-to-install-wordpress-with-softaculous), then it's really down to hostgator to see you right and work with you to remedy, given it's offered as a one-click install option through their cpanel.

That said, i'd be inclined to the follow what's said here first.

https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/error-messages-during-one-click-wordpress-install

And if you're still getting nowhere trying again with the auto install method, then i'd be thinking about doing it the hands on way, manually.

Your host offers instructions for doing this.
https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/how-to-install-wordpress-manually